# Filling model list property in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model with a list property. In my view the user will fill in a fixed number of similar data (name number etc). How can I collect that information and create a list of it on the post? Thanks for any help.

```
public class mainonject
{
    public List<test> list{ get; set; }
}

public class test
{
    string name;
    string number;
}

<form>
    HOW DO I COLLECT THE PROPERTY list AS A LIST TO THE SERVER
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: You prob. are looking at custom binding on complex property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the fields to your form and use the right indexes in there name properties:

```
<input name="list[0].Name" type="text" />
<input name="list[0].Number" type="text" />

<input name="list[1].Name" type="text" />
<input name="list[1].Number" type="text" />
```

...